# selenium python verify the element is not present

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to verify that the element is not present in the DOM:

I have written this function:

```
def verifyElementNotFound(self, xpath):
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    if element.is_displayed():
        raise Exception("Element should not be found")
    else:
        pass
```

The element is not present in the dom but it is giving me this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[.="DO NOT DELETE: Regression Test script 2"]"}
```

or can i use this intead, is this a robust way to do it?

```
try:
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    if element.is_displayed():
        raise Exception("Element should not be found")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: I'm a little confused of what you are looking for here, could you describe it better. what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @Kliffy, the error is in the main question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this not sure if this is what you want.

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

if len(element):
    print("element is present")
elif:
    print("element is not present")
```

please let me know if this worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

Since the element is not present on the DOM, the line

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

will throw `NoSuchElementException`, because the `WebDriver` couldn't even locate the element. Having this line in a try-catch block will also work (like your 2nd code) or you can also use @Kliffy's  approach of using `find_elements_by_xpath`, which automatically handles any exception & returns an empty list if element is not found, else returns all the matching elements in a list. So all you have to do is check if the length of the list returned by `find_elements_by_xpath` is equal to 0 to assert that the element is not present.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check that an element does not exist, the easiest way to do that is using a with statement.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def test_element_does_not_exist(self):
    with self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```